# SharpDevelop: developing plugins

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, add-in, sharpdevelop

I'd like to implement a small feature (getting default `Style`s and `ControlTemplate`s for WPF controls) that is missing in SharpDevelop vs. Visual Studio. I'm facing the problem that I do not understand what is considered to be the public API surface for the [WpfDesign.Designer](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/tree/master/src/AddIns/DisplayBindings/WpfDesign/WpfDesign.Designer/Project) addin that I'd like to extend.

Is there an established mechanism for addins to declare in what ways other addins may extend them (addins extending other addins is explicitly allowed in the SharpDevelop architecture)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public API surface is all the public types in the WpfDesign.Designer assemblies. You can reference them directly and specify this in your addin's .addin file so the designer addin is loaded before your addin is loaded.

```
<Manifest>
    <Identity name="YourAddInId"/>
    <Dependency addin="ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit" requirePreload="true"/>
</Manifest>
```

Using the public types is the simplest way to extend an existing addin. You reference the designer assemblies, but do not have them copied locally to your addin's output directory.

There are other ways to extend SharpDevelop using extension paths in the addin system. This allows you to have addins that do not depend on each other. The WPFDesigner addin does not define any extension points/paths as far as I am aware so I would just directly reference the designer assemblies and use them.

Also another approach to consider would be to add the changes directly to the SharpDevelop source code and submit a pull request so they can be included in SharpDevelop directly. However an addin might be useful to as a proof of concept.